# Difference between authentication token and access token in Live Connect?

Tags: windows-8, access-token

The Live Connect session includes both authentication token and access token and I'm slightly confused about the use of either of these. I use authentication token to verify the users login to live from my web service backend - what is the access token for? Does it have something to do with accessing the live resources on the live account or can I use it to do something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help, regarding access token

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_token